# ajax jquery - post csv file to php one line at a time

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-post

I want to do this:

- user load a csv file
- it reads the data one by one
- php do the processing, it takes quite some time
- php enter the process to mysql

problems are:

- csv file is too large, so the php hit the 30 secs time limit.
- the processed data should be entered to sql in order and one by one
- running just the php, the connection to mysql can't keep up, so far i need to separate the csv to 30 lines per file so it could be entered correctly to mysql.

I think combining with jquery:

- jquery reads the file
- jquery pause 1 second per csv line
- jquery is client side so it won't have time limitation
- jquery then call php which in turn will send to mysql

I'm stuck with jquery, because it sends the data in csv in non-ordered way.

What I need help is to pause the jquery.post one by one in example 1 second interval each.

here's the code that i've come up so far. i need the "pausing" effect for each post

```
<script>
$(function () {
var o1;
var o2;
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});

$('#load').click(function () {
    $.get($('#file').val(), function (content) {
        //get the file and convert into single array
        o1 = content.split(new RegExp("\n")).map(function (element) {return $.trim(element).toLowerCase();})

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------- Display
        $("#box").empty();
        $.each(o1,
            function( i, j ){
                if (j!=""){
                    //add the tr
                    //$("#tbl").append($( "<tr id=\"tr-"+i+"\"></tr>" ));

                    //split again
                    o2 = j.split(new RegExp(",|\r")).map(function (element) {return $.trim(element).toLowerCase();});
                    $.post('test2.php',{jquery:'1' , d:o2[0] , o:o2[1] , h:o2[2] , l:o2[3] , c:o2[4]},function(res){
                        $("#box").append(res);
                    });
                }//end if
            }//end function
        );//end each
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------- end of display

     });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="file" type="file" />
<input type="button" id="load" value="Load CSV" />
</form>
<hr />
<table id="tbl" border="1"><tbody></tbody></table>
<div id="box"></div>
<ol id="list"></ol>
</body>
```

and this is the 'test2.php' file content. it's just an example of what i will do, the real code is of course more complex:

```
if ($_POST){
    @$_POST['jquery']!=''?$jquery=$_POST['jquery']:$jquery='';
    if ($jquery!=''){
        @$_POST['d']!=''?$d=$_POST['d']:$d='';
        @$_POST['o']!=''?$o=$_POST['o']:$o='';
        @$_POST['h']!=''?$h=$_POST['h']:$h='';
        @$_POST['l']!=''?$l=$_POST['l']:$l='';
        @$_POST['c']!=''?$c=$_POST['c']:$c='';
        echo 'D: '.$d.' - '.$o.' - '.$h.' - '.$l.' - '.$c."<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Really need help here. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but let me get this more clearer: when you try to upload the file, you get a timeout because the file is too big, and when you try to make ajax calls to send the file in parts, you get a problem that your mysql is slower than your client sending you jquery calls?

Comment: not quite. on php+mysql, i get php timeout because the csv file is too big. on jquery, the csv file is not entered in order, which is a must. on jquery it is entered 2 or 3 lines at a time, some kind of parallel, resulting in wrong data counting. fyi, one of the csv file could have around 30k lines with 5 columns each, the 1st columns being the date.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm not a strong supporter of the way you're approaching the problem...

**to STOP jQuery from making assync calls**: `async: false`

You can do this in jQuery: `$.ajaxSetup({async:false});` and then issue your regular call to `$.post`. [More info on the manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Thank you Frankie. It fixed the problem. I can't believe it's that simple. It took me 2 days trying everything with no result being a newbie as me.

Comment: @William great! Now, in Stack Overflow style (SO) you should accept the answer if you think it helped you. That way you'll improve my reputation and you'll also get some points for yourself. You probably should spend 3 minutes reading the FAQ to familiarize yourself with the community. http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Welcome to SO.